# R issue on optim() with a function depending on a loop

Tags: r, optimization

it's a simple issue about optim() function on R. I am trying to find the mimimum of a function depending on a loop's variable.

```
f<-function(x,i){
  i*x
}

M<-matrix(0,10,1)

  for (i in 1:5) {
    M[i,1]<-optim(c(1),f,lower=-2,upper=2,method="L-BFGS-B")
  }
M
```

R answers me :

```
Erreur dans i * x : 'i' est manquant
```

I really don't understand how to deal with this one....

Comment: Please note that a lot of people on SO do not speak French. So for future questions I would recommend translating the error message from French to English. Alternatively, you could switch R to an English locale...

Comment: Google does a pretty good job [translating stuff like this](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|Erreur%20dans%20i%20*%20x%20%3A%20%27i%27%20est%20manquant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `i` to the `optim` call:

```
optim(1,f,i=i,lower=-2,upper=2,method="L-BFGS-B")
```

...and `optim` returns a list, so you need to pick which element in the list you want to store in `M`.  I assume you want `par`:

```
M[i,1] <- optim(1,f,i=i,lower=-2,upper=2,method="L-BFGS-B")$par
```

UPDATE:

As Justin pointed out in the comments, the more R-like way to do this would be:

```
L <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
    L[[i]] <- optim(1,f,i=i,lower=-2,upper=2,method="L-BFGS-B")
}
V <- sapply(L, `[[`, "par")
```

Comment: You win!  I wrote the same thing, but added the potential step of initializing M as a list and saving all the output from optim.

Comment: @Justin: that's probably a better solution... I'll edit it in; thanks!